# How do i fix the undo history bug in PHPEclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, phpeclipse

[PHPEclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/)'s undo history is still broken in Eclipse 3.8 with PHPEclipse 1.2.x.

You are able to undo **only 25 changes back in history** when editing PHP files!

There is no installation instruction for 3.8 on the PHPEclipse site, so I used **PHPEclipse 1.2.x** as stated on the installtation page: http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Installation

On the main tracker page for this bug it sais, it was fixed by now: 
http://www.phpeclipse.com/ticket/705

I asked the developer. He said, this is still not part of the 1.2.x stable build but on the nightly build.

on the PHPEclipse page on the right, there is this:

> 1.2.x dev nightly for Indigo (eclipse 3.8.1)
>    [1.2.x Nightly Update Site](http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/indigo/nightly)

So how do I install that nightly build, if I already prior installed the stable build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem when installing the nightly build is, that the checkbox "Group items by category" may not be checked, otherwise you don't see any packages to select!

To install PHPEclipse nightly build under

```
Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites
```

select:

​http://phpeclipse.sourceforge.net/update/indigo/nightly/

(be sure, that the checkbox "Group items by category" is not checked!)

in case you've prior installed the stable release of PHPEclipse uninstall those three Entries first (PHPEclipse, Xdebug and DBG) under 'What is already installed' in the bottom right corner of that screen